# How to remove digits from beginning of filename?

Tags: batch-file

I need to rename a filename like this `7612372 filename 50x50.jpg` into this `filename 50x50.jpg`, removing all digits at the beginning of the filename.
The number of digit can be variable.

I need to integrate this into an existing batch file run from the Windows command prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the format of the filename would be the same for **all** the files in the folder, then you can try:

```bat
@echo off

for /F "delims=" %%A IN ('dir /b /A-D') do (
    for /F "tokens=2-3" %%B IN ("%%A") do (
        ren "%%~fA" "%%B %%C"
    )
)
```

This is the shortest way, but not the most accurate one. It is unsecure, because if the `filename` contains spaces, the file will be rename incorrectly. I suggest the following code for the task:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%A IN ('dir /b /A-D') do (
    set filename=%%A
    for /F "tokens=1" %%B IN ("%%A") do (
        ren "%%~fA" "!filename:%%B =!"
    )
)
```

which is more accurate and renames all files correctly **only if they have the format mentioned in the beginning**.

- `@echo off` turns command-echoing **off**.
- `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` enables [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). We use it **only** here, as we have to access variables inside a `for` loop which is a code block. You must use delayed expansion always inside these code blocks.
- Now we make a `for` loop to **parse the output** (`/F`) of the `dir /b /A-D` command which lists all items in current working directory (`%cd%`), **excluding directories** (`/A-D`).

  - We need to set a variable here with the filename. We could use the variable name of the loop (`%%A`), but variables have an advantage: `%var:search=replace%`, or even `!var:search=replace!` which we need here.
  - Now we make another `for` loop to **parse a string** (`/F`): the filename (`%%A`). We need to access the first token to substract it later. We don't really need to specify it here, but it is good to make it clearer.

    - We rename files now: `%%~fA` is the full path where filename currently processed is and `!filename:%%B =!` means to take `filename` environment variable, search for string `"%%B "` (first part of filename [digits] and a space) and replace it with an empty string; actually nothing!

Comment: seems having a little bug: it remove the first word if it contain digits. All word and not only the digit before firs letter:

This name 
"03T30 NAME T ALL 40X40X2 - Copy.JPG" 
become 
"NAME T ALL 40X40X2 - Copy.JPG"

but should be
"T30 NAME T ALL 40X40X2 - Copy.JPG"

Comment: @lotux777 Also such a file renaming can be done easily with using Windows command processor as third solution in my updated answer demonstrates. The limited regular expression capabilities of __FINDSTR__ are enough for this task.

Comment: @double-beep As my answer proves no PowerShell neccessary here.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest following batch code for this task:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%A in ('dir "* *" /A-D-H /B 2^>nul') do for /F "tokens=1*" %%B in ("%%A") do ren "%%A" "%%C"
pause
```

The command **FOR** runs with `cmd.exe /C` (more precise `%ComSpec% /C`) in a separate command process in background the command line:

```
dir "* *" /A-D-H /B 2>nul
```

**DIR** outputs to handle **STDOUT** of this background command process

- just the names of all non-hidden files because of option `/A-D-H` (attribute not directory and not hidden)
- in bare format because of option `/B` without file path
- matching the wildcard pattern `* *` which matches any file name with at least one space inside
- in current directory which can but must not be the directory of the batch file.

**DIR** would output an error message to handle **STDERR** if it can't find any directory entry matching these criteria. This error message is redirected to device **NUL** to suppress it.

Read the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

**FOR** captures all lines output to handle **STDOUT** of started command process and processes those lines after started `cmd.exe` terminated itself. It is very important for this file renaming task that **FOR** runs on a list of file names captured before doing the file renames as otherwise the directory entries would change while **FOR** is accessing them. For that reason `for` can't be used directly in this case because of `for` would process the list of `* *` directory entries while this list changes on each successful file rename. The result would be files not renamed or renamed multiple times or even an endless running loop depending on file system (NTFS or a FAT file system like FAT32 or ExFAT).

**FOR** with option `/F` ignores empty lines which do not occur here. **FOR** ignores also lines starting with a semicolon because of end of line option `eol=;` is the default. But all lines output by **DIR** should start with a number and for that reason the default end of line definition can be kept for this task.

**FOR** with option `/F` splits up a line by default to substrings using normal space and horizontal tab as delimiters and assigns just first space/tab separated string to specified loop variable. This line splitting behavior is not wanted here in outer **FOR** loop because loop variable `A` should hold complete file name with all spaces. Therefore `delims=` is used to define an empty list of delimiters to disable the line splitting behavior. Safer would be `"delims= eol="` which defines also no end of line character.

The file name assigned to loop variable `A` is referenced with `%%A` as string in inner **FOR** loop which splits up the file name into two substrings (tokens). The first substring is the number assigned to specified loop variable `B`. The second substring after first sequence of spaces (tabs not possible in a file name) is assigned without any further splitting to next loop variable `C` according to [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/). In other words on file name `7612372 filename 50x50.jpg` loop variable `B` holds `7612372` and `filename 50x50.jpg` is assigned to loop variable `C`.

The command **REN** renames the file by referencing complete file name as assigned to loop variable `A` to the part after first sequence of spaces as assigned to loop variable `C`.

The command **PAUSE** at end is added to see the error message output by command **REN** if renaming a file failed. There is nothing output except the prompt by **PAUSE** on all files could be renamed successfully.

The batch code can be enhanced further by using **FINDSTR** as filter to make sure that a file to rename starts really with one or more digits up to first space by using this code:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%A in ('dir "* *" /A-D-H /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /C:"^[0123456789][0123456789]* "') do for /F "tokens=1*" %%B in ("%%A") do ren "%%A" "%%C"
pause
```

One more variant for renaming a file with name `03T30 NAME T ALL 40X40X2 - Copy.JPG` to `T30 NAME T ALL 40X40X2 - Copy.JPG`:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%A in ('dir /A-D-H /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "^[0123456789][0123456789]*"') do for /F "tokens=* delims=0123456789 " %%B in ("%%A") do ren "%%A" "%%B"
pause
```

**DIR** outputs the names of all non-hidden files in current directory. This output is redirected as input for **FINDSTR** which checks if the file name starts with one or more digits. Only those file names are output to **STDOUT** of background command process to be processed next by **FOR**.

The inner **FOR** interprets all digits and space character as string delimiters because of `delims=0123456789`  and assigns everything after first sequence of digits or spaces to loop variable `B` because of `tokens=*`. So loop variable `B` holds `filename 50x50.jpg` with `7612372 filename 50x50.jpg` assigned to `A` and `T30 NAME T ALL 40X40X2 - Copy.JPG` for file name `03T30 NAME T ALL 40X40X2 - Copy.JPG`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `pause /?`
- `ren /?`

PS: I recommend the usage of the shareware file manager Total Commander which has a built-in multi-rename tool for renaming files and folders for people with no coding experience. Download, install and start Total Commander, navigate to the folder containing all these files, press <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> to select the files, press <kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd> to open multi-rename tool window and the rest is self-explaining. If you need nevertheless help, press key <kbd>F1</kbd> to open the help page for multi-rename tool.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not specific enough for us to provide a solution, you really need to provide the section of code into which you wish this to be integrated.

This one expects only one file, as in your question, and that file must be named in the format you've indicated, i.e. the required part is separated from the non-required part by a space:

```bat
@Set "name=7612372 filename 50x50.jpg"
@Ren "%name%" "%name:* =%"
```

[Edit /]

I have noted from your comments that you were indeed looking to parse several files and those files did not match the naming scheme you provided in your question.

Here therefore is an updated potential solution based on those changed parameters.

```bat
@For %%A In (*.*) Do @For /F "Tokens=* Delims=0123456789 " %%B In ("%%A") Do @Ren "%%~A" "%%B"
```

*Apologies to LotPings, who I've noticed has posted a very similar method/solution*

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution is to use

- all digits and space as delims and
- tokens=*

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\01\06\SO_54054587.cmd
for /F "delims=" %%A in (
    'dir "* *" /A-D-H /B 2^>nul'
) do for /F "tokens=* delims=0123456789 " %%B in (
    "%%A"
) do ren "%%A" "%%B"
```

this will remove **all** leading delimiters while **not** splitting the remainder of the file name.

Like the other answers this will not account for the shorted file name already being present.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple with the basic DOS command **`rename`**.

> 7612372 filename 50x50.jpg

If this is your sample file in the folder, it contains 7 digits and 1 blank space. Totally 8 characters.

We can do this by simply running this command on the particular folder

```
rename "*.mp3" "////////*.mp3"
```

each / represents a character you want to remove. That's it.